# Super hard battery drain and high temperatures

Tags: nvidia, power-management, laptop, battery, temperature

I am new to Ubuntu, recently switched from Windows. I wanted it to be my primary OS. The problem is, that my battery life time under Ubuntu is like **EXTREMELY** low, it takes my *Acer Aspire 7* with a new battery less than 1 hour to discharge, while under Windows i could use it like 4 to 5 hours (or even more with Wi-Fi disabled).

I have already disabled my Nvidia GTX1060 in the *Nvidia X server* (using intel only), downloaded *TLP* and an app called *Slimbook Battery* - none of them helped. Did not manage to run *Bumblebee*, but resigned as the Nvidia app does basically the same.

What is more, the fans are working fast and the notebook is getting hot. I assume it is connected with horrible optimalization, as GTX1060 and i7 8750H can be really power-hungry under big load. The problem is it happens with only Chrome opened at the lowest screen brightness possible.

Also, while using Windows installed on the secondary disk it runs completely fine.

I really liked the do-it-yourself idea with the system, I'd like to stick to Ubuntu for a little bit longer. But I do need the battery life as I work a lot in travel, so is there another way to improve the battery life? I read a lot of topics similar to this one, but none of them actually managed to solve the problem, and many of them are just old. I am afraid i will have change the OS again, as I really do need at least these 3 hours.

I am running **Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS**

I'd be grateful if u helped a bit. Thanks

Comment: Have you turned on "Hardware acceleration" in Chrome? (Settings/Advanced/System). It may make a difference to switch this on or off.

Comment: Yes, it was on. I have just disabled it, as well as background processes when chrome is closed. Frankly, i did not know these options exist, I will have to test it now, thanks. I'll let you know if it helped

Answer (score 1):

I have had the exact same problem on my Laptop. I have a Dell G3 15 with NVIDIA graphics card. The symptoms are the same as yours. After many hours of google I finally found that there were new drivers for my NVIDIA card. Installing this made the battery life go up to what was expected. I found this under the software and updates and the additional drivers section. Its also the same place I was able to disable the Intel drivers.

Comment: Actually the only thing I managed to do is I messed up with the system and probably disabled GUI permanently. The system wouldn't boot at all (it would lag just before login) after my manual configuration of Nvidia drivers. Do not ask how :P. 
I reinstalled Windows again as I needed a working OS for my work tomorrow. No idea if it would help, but thanks anyway.
I think I will give it up for now, as it was my last desperate begging for help. There's nothing more I can do. Gonna try it once again one day when I'm bored

Comment: Try a live boot, so that it runs directly from a usb drive/cd. See if it works there first before trying again in the future.